# Find ![image](url) using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Input: `This is my image url: ![image](www.example.com/images/abcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg)`

Expetec output: `This is my image url: too long`

I tried

```
string.replace(/\![^)]*\)/g,'too long')
```

which replaces string from `!` to `)`. But I believe replacing string from `![image](` to `)` will be more accurate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\!\[[^\]\]]+\]\(([^\)]*)\)
```

Breakdown:

- `\!` Match a `!` character
- `\[[^\]]+\]` Match a `[` character, some text, and a `]` character
- `\(([^\)]+)` Match a `(` character, then create a CAPTURE GROUP for the contents of the parentheses, and then a `)`

You can then access that capture group directly (the URL will be capture-group #1; capture group #0 is the full string as it was matched.)

You can test this regex out live at [Regexr](https://regexr.com/4ogcv), where you can also mouse over the results to find the different groups and how they're interpreted by the regex.

Comment: Thank you, but the solution leaves a `)` at the end of the string

Comment: Make sure you're replacing the capture group, not the full match. If you'd rather, I can give you a regex that only matches the inside of the parens!

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

Maybe, a simple match and concat might work here:

```js
const regex = /^[^:]+:/gm;
const str = `This is my image url: ![image](www.example.com/images/abcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(match.concat(' too long'));
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/26R5Gm/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/26R5Gm/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Method 2

If you might have some other similar contexts in your inputs, we can try a more dexterous expression, if that'd be necessary:

```js
const regex = /(.+?)(!\[image\]\s*\((?:https?)?(?:w{3}\.)?[^)]*\))/gm;
const str = `This is my image url: ![image](www.example.com/images/abcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg)`;
const subst = `$1too long`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/RrAE7t/1/)

---

#### Method 3

Might be unnecessary, but lookahead assertion is another option too:

```js
const regex = /.+?(?=!\[image\]\s*\((?:https?)?(?:w{3}\.)?[^)]*\))/gm;
const str = `This is my image url 1: ![image](www.example.com/images/abcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg)
 
This is my image url 2: ![image](https://www.example.com/images/abcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefgabcdefg)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(match.concat(' too long'));
    });
}
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/uMHsQw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `!\[image\]\([^)]+\)`

Explanation:

`!` - match `!` literally

`\[image\]` - match `[image]` literally

`\(` - match `(` literally

`[^)]+` - match one or more of characters other from `)`

`\)` - match `)` literally

And repace it with: `too long`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HLV83b/1)